# Is there a way to sum an entire quantity in SQL with unique values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a total summation of both the ItemDetail.Quantity column and ItemDetail.NetPrice column.  For sake of example, let's say the quantity that is listed is for each individual item is 5, 2, and 4 respectively.  I am wondering if there is a way to display quantity as 11 for one single ItemGroup.ItemGroupName

The query I am using is listed below

```
select Location.LocationName, ItemDetail.DOB, SUM (ItemDetail.Quantity) as "Quantity",
       ItemGroup.ItemGroupName, SUM (ItemDetail.NetPrice)
from ItemDetail
Join ItemGroupMember
    on ItemDetail.ItemID = ItemGroupMember.ItemID
Join ItemGroup
    on ItemGroupMember.ItemGroupID = ItemGroup.ItemGroupID
Join Location
    on ItemDetail.LocationID = Location.LocationID
Inner Join Item
    on ItemDetail.ItemID = Item.ItemID
where ItemGroup.ItemGroupID = '78' and DOB = '11/20/2019'
GROUP BY Location.LocationName, ItemDetail.DOB, Item.ItemName,
         ItemDetail.NetPrice, ItemGroup.ItemGroupName
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set function.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Start by removing everything but `ItemGroup.ItemGroupName` from your `group by` clause.  Remove `Location.LocationName` and `ItemDetail.DOB` from your select clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 , you can use the summation on partition to display the 
details and aggregates in the same query.

SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate)),1)

Link : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

We can't be certain without seeing sample data.  But I suspect you need to remove some fields from you `GROUP BY` clause -- probably `Item.ItemName` and `ItemDetail.NetPrice`.

Generally, you won't GROUP BY a column that you are applying an aggregate function to in the SELECT -- as in `SUM(ItemDetail.NetPrice)`.  And it is not very common, in my experience, to GROUP BY columns that aren't included in the SELECT list - as you are doing with `Item.ItemName`.

I think you need to go back to basics and read about what `GROUP BY` does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to the overflow...

Second: The answer is going to be "It depends"
Any time you aggregate data you will need to Group by the other fields in the query, and you have that in the query. The gotcha is what happens when data is spread across multiple locations.

My suggestion is to rethink your problem and see if you really need these other fields in the query. This will depend on what the person using the data really wants to know.

Do they need to know how many of item X there are, or do they really need to know that item X is spread out over three sites?

You might find you are better off with two smaller queries.

Comment: When I run the query this is what I get out:

Location Name DOB Quantity ItemGroupName Column1
Site Number 11/20/2019 2 FSR - Everything with Salad Bar 43.98
Site Number 11/20/2019 1 FSR - Everything with Salad Bar 0
Site Number 11/20/2019 2 FSR - Everything with Salad Bar 21.98

What I would like is:

Location Name DOB Quantity ItemGroupName Column1
Site Number 11/20/2019 5 FSR - Everything with Salad Bar 65.96

I'm basically looking to get the quantity and column1 to be a single row.